# Why is this nonlinear system of differential equations giving me the exact same results using a coupled and uncoupled analysis?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Consider the following coupled system of differential equations:

[image: Text]

Our unknowns are the functions $u_1(t)$, $u_2(t)$ and $u_{GV}(t)$

Let's say $k_{GV}$ is a nonlinear function of the form $k_3=f(u_{GV})$.

$F_1$ and $F_{GV}$ are functions of time imagine sine waves for example. All the other terms appearing in the system are constants.

Now lets say I solve the system and obtain all the results $u_1$, $u_2$ and $u_{GV}$.

I decide then to consider the following problem:

$m_{GV}\ddot{u}_{GV}(t)-k_3u_2(t)+(k_3+k_{GV})u_{GV}(t)=F_{GV}$

In this problem I consider that the terms $\ddot{u}_{GV}$ and ${u}_{GV}$ are unknowns but I consider the same $u_2(t)$ that we obtained earlier. I solve again for ${u}_{GV}$.

Logically shouldn't the new function ${u}_{GV}$ that I obtain be different from the one I obtained from the full system earlier?

I did some simulations on Mathematica and used different $k_{GV}$ some of which are very non linear but I always obtained the same solution. Does this make sense? Is there something I'm not understanding well?

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand why you think the solution would be different?

Comment: @maxmilgram I thought hat due to the non linearties I will see differences in the solutions especially when the problem is scaled into thousands of equations. Is there like a proof why this won't happen?